# What event fires when item in HTML select/dropdown list is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to respond to the user selecting an item in a select element. Yet this jQuery:

```
$('#platypusDropDown').select(function () {
    alert('You selected something');
});
```

...does nothing. It shows no alert, although jsFiddle sees it as valid jQuery.

The Click event works, but it's too fast - it fires on clicking the select element, prior to making a selection.

Of course, I really want to do something like:

```
$('#platypusDropDown').select(function () {
    var selection = $('platypusDropDown').val;
    $.getJSON('platypus.json', selection, data() {
        // . . .
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<select id="platypusDropDown">
    <option value="duckbill">duckbill</option>
    <option value="duckbillPlatypus">duckbillPlatypus</option>
    <option value="Platypus">Platypus</option>
    <option value="Platypi">Platypi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use **[change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event

```
$('#platypusDropDown').change(function () {
    var selection = this.value; //grab the value selected
    $.getJSON('platypus.json', selection, data() {
    . . .
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tJHh/)**

Plus `$('platypusDropDown').val` here val should be `val()` and you dont need to create a jquery object again over the element, `this` inside the handler represents DOM element (select on which the event is bound to) and you can directly access the value with `this.value` or `$(this).val()`