# Javascript function action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok so in my previous website I had a small javascript that checks the DB if a username that is inputed already exists. And was working excellent.
Now i have a different but similar requirement, i need to check for values from the option tag and output an X or OK when the option was changed.

HERE'S THE CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#subcat").change(function(event) {

        var xhr = $.post("php/check.php", {subcat1: $(this).val()});

            xhr.done(function(result) {
                $("#check-cat").html(result).show();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

HERE'S THE HTML:

```
<select id="type" name="subcat">

<option value="0">Izaberi kategoriju prvo...</option>

</select>


<span id="check-cat" style="color:red; font-size: 18px;">X</span>
```

And the file that is checking for the POST data:

AND THE CHECK.PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['subcat1'])){

    if($_POST['subcat1'] == '0'){
        echo 'X!';
    } else{
        echo 'OK!';
    }
}

?>
```

In the javascript part there is something  missing i really don't know what to put in there so that the function was called.

Thank you for the help. if anything else is needed just put it in the comments and I will add it.

Comment: you need a button event or change event

Comment: possible duplicate of [What event fires when item in HTML select/dropdown list is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414390/what-event-fires-when-item-in-html-select-dropdown-list-is-selected)

Comment: How can it be a duplicate when i call an external file to do something. But the question you have posted is internal only!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand exactly what you want, but I think this is on the right path

```
$("#subcat").change(function(event) {

  var xhr = $.post("php/db/functions/check.php", {subcat1: $(this).val()});

  xhr.done(function(result) {
    $("#check-cat").html(result).show();
  });
});
```

When the `#subcat` selector is changed, it will send make an ajax post request each time.

Comment: Ok I've eddited the question with your example and it's still not working. there's again somethnig wrong.. :/ Can you help me?